# Как заставить ufw применить новые правила?

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

После внесения изменения в файл /etc/ufw/before.rules пытаюсь применить новые правила, ничего не выходит.
ufw start|stop|restart|reload
service ufw start|stop|restart|reload
не помогают.
Единственный выход, который я нашёл, чтобы правила применились - полностью перезагрузить сервер.
Есть какой-то способ заставить эту бесполезную утилиту работать или стоит её сразу снести и работать с iptables напрямую?

Comment: Я делаю обычно disable/enable

Comment: restart у меня всегда отлично работал